# MS Access query to get last 2 days

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to get the last 2 days records using this query:

```
select [DATE_COLUMN] from [TABLE] where ([DATE_COLUMN] >= NOW()-2)
```

What should I modify to get the same result, but using

```
MAX([DATE_COLUMN])-2
```

instead of

```
[DATE_COLUMN] >= NOW()-2

MAX([DATE_COLUMN]) --returns 20/10/2015, so I would like to get 20/10/2015 19/10/2015 18/10/2015
```

Thank you!

Comment: `... WHERE [DATE_COLUMN] >= (SELECT max([date_column])-2 FROM [table])` would work in most Databases. I've never tried it in Access, but I'm betting it would work.

Comment: Watch out for Now(), it includes time, Date() does not. In general, be careful of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can used the DateAdd function:

```
SELECT [DATE_COLUMN]
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [DATE_COLUMN] >= (SELECT DateAdd("d", -2, Max([DATE_COLUMN])) FROM [TABLE])
```